# Thymeleaf conditional image insert under conditional

Tags: java, spring, if-statement, thymeleaf

I am trying to execute conditional in Thymeleaf :

```
 <img th:src="${{chat.sender.id} == ${#authentication.principal.user.id} ?: '/img/' + ${chat.sender.userProfile.avatar} : '/img/' + ${chat.receiver.userProfile.avatar} }"/>
```

But I am getting the error :

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "{chat.sender.id} == ${#authentication.principal.user.id} ?: '/img/' + ${chat.sender.userProfile.avatar} : '/img/' + ${chat.receiver.userProfile.avatar} " (template: "chat/friends-chat" - line 28, col 18)
```

Please explain me what I am doing incorrectly .

Answer (score 1):

You should not wrap the whole block in ${ }.  Also change ?: to ?, it looks like a typo.
Try with

```
 <img th:src="${chat.sender.id} == ${#authentication.principal.user.id} ? '/img/' + ${chat.sender.userProfile.avatar} : '/img/' + ${chat.receiver.userProfile.avatar} "/>
```